# imp.load_source() throwing "No Module Named" Error Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

I'm currently using Python 2.7, and I'm trying to load a file like this:

```
myPlt = imp.load_source('SourceFile', 'path/to/SourceFile.py')
```

However, SourceFile.py imports module OtherModule, which is in the same directory as SourceFile. The package structure looks like this:

```
/path
 .../to
      ...SourceFile.py
      ...OtherModule.py
      ...__init__.py
```

When I run the load_source, I get the error "ImportError: No module named OtherModule"

Is my load_source call incorrect? Is there an alternate way I should go about importing SourceFile?

Comment: load `OtherModule.py` first?

Comment: Why don't you load the entire package directly?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Sure I could try that, but what would be the syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

imp.load_source("directory", "directory" + "filename.py")

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to return the same error..do I need an __init__.py file in each folder in the directory path? I currently only have it in the folder with the scripts themselves

Comment: No. You don't. Just to be clear, which file is loading which file? I was under the impression OtherModule calls this loading statement SourceFile.py...If they're in the same directory, you should do imp.load_source(".", "SourceFile.py") If you want to load SourceFile.py